# Advantage 5400 AE_INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, advantage-database-server

I am getting a 5400 AE_INTERNAL_ERROR when I try to OPEN a TadsQuery after adding the SQL. When I place the same SQL directly in the TadsQuery , there is no error. Your Help File directs me to contact Advantage Technical Support so R & D can fix the problem. Technical Support suggested that I post here.

Here is a snipit of code (suggested by Doug Johnson):

```
if (Value = '**') or (StartUp) then
with DM1.qadSBSort do
begin
  DisableControls;
for i := 1 to 26 do
begin
  if Active then Close;
  Active := False;
  HText := 'SELECT SBName, SBPath FROM poSBSorted ' +
           ' WHERE [SBName LIKE ''' + CHR(i + 64) + '''] ' +
           ' ORDER BY SBName';
  SQL.Clear();
  SQL.Text := HText;
  try
     try
        Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
        Open();

     finally
        Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
     end;

  except
     On E: Exception do
     begin
        if( E.Message <> 'The SQL statement did not '+
              'generate a cursor handle.  Use ' +
              'TAdsQuery.ExecSQL to execute SQL ' +
              'statements that are not SELECT statements' )then
           MessageDlg( E.Message, mtWarning, [ mbOK ], 0 );
     end;
  end;
  Active := True;
```

Here are the system stats:

Processor: INTEL® Core™2 DUO CPU @ 2.00GHz 2.00 Ghz
Installed Memory: 4.00 GB
System type: 64bit. 
OS: Windows 7. 
Programming: Delphi 2010.
Advantage version:  9.10 64bit
Server: Local.
Tables: Free.
Please advise. Thank you and have a good day.

-Bob Andrews

Comment: Technical support engineer told customer to go and ask around in the internets?!

Comment: My technical support?? stackoverflow technical support? mmm... it sounds you just copy/paste the question from somewhere else.

Comment: Before you go all postal on Advantage, Advantage sells to developers who then resell it with their applications to clients.  Advantage provides their engine free for development.  Advantage supports developers directly who have a relationship with the company, not just anyone who calls in.  And, indeed, they expect those of us who develop with Advantage to support our own clients. They DO however monitor this site, support it and contribute to it, so it is not an unreasonable thing to suggest.  That Advantage sent OP here would indicate that, in fact, he is not a customer of Advantage.

Comment: It would be helpful if you had a bit of code.  The error you are getting is vague, as is the question, so if you could be more specific, I might be able to assist.  I looked up the error you are getting and it indicates that it is a JDBC driver error, but you indicate you are using a TADSQuery, so more specificity may allow me to help.

Comment: Post the actual SQL (not Delphi code, but the actual fully written SQL) you're wanting to run. I see several problems with the query as written, but it's hard to tell if the problem is in the SQL or the Delphi code. (I fixed the formatting so it's at least readable.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of ADS error codes: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.1/mergedprojects/adserror/err5xxx/advantage_5xxx_error_codes.htm

Error # [5400](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage9.1/mergedprojects/adserror/err5xxx/5400_ae_internal_error.htm) States

```
This error is an Advantage JDBC Driver internal error. Please send a small re-creation to Advantage Technical Support demonstrating the problem so that Advantage R&D can fix the issue.
```

I would post some code on their newsgroups: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=7

Or get a developer account and request support.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL makes no sense. Your query (for a value of i = 1) is literally

```
SELECT SBName, SBPath FROM poSBSorted 
 WHERE [SBName LIKE 'A']
 ORDER BY SBName
```

That is not valid SQL for Advantage, and generates

```
poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = 42000;   NativeError = 2115;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Expected lexical 
element not found: IN, NOT IN, LIKE, NOT LIKE, BETWEEN, NOT BETWEEN There was a problem parsing the WHERE clause in your 
SELECT statement
```

If I change it to be proper ADS SQL:

```
SELECT SBName, SBPath FROM poSBSorted 
 WHERE SBName LIKE 'A%'
 ORDER BY SBName
```

It works fine with a dummy poSBSorted db containing two Char(10) columns to represent SBName and SBPath.

As I said in my comment above, post the actual plain SQL you're trying to use (or at least explain your database schema, sample data, and the results you're trying to obtain), and perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: What I am trying to do is sort my database into alphabetical groups.  Notice CHR(i + 64).  That is not the problem I need help with. Please explain to me why ERROR  5400 happens when I try to open the TadsQuery which does not happen when I activate the same TadsQuery in the data module.

Answer (score 1):

I can't duplicate the 5400 error that you are getting, but there are enough questions in the code snippet that you submit that I am going to give you some general guidelines.
Without more code, I can't do much better for you than Ken did, but I will give you some things to try.
I can't tell if you are using an ADSConnection or not, but you are going to have problems if you do not.
Your SQL statement needs to be modified as Ken suggests.  It doesn't work otherwise.
You need to make sure your ADSQuery matches the table type that you are using.

The fact that I see DM1, might indicate that you are doing this in a DLL?

I guess the good news is that you are getting a weird error and the two of us who tried to duplicate it can accomplish what you are trying to accomplish, without the error, by making some simple changes.

As an additional note, you don't need to do both Active and Open.  When you open your query it goes active or if you set Active to true, it opens the query.  And, purely stylistically, you don't need the parens after the methods unless there are parameters.  Neither one of those is causing your problem (I'd bet on an ADSconnection issue) but just a note.

The code change that I made to your SQL statement looks just like Ken's.

```
  HText := 'SELECT SBName, SBPath FROM poSBSorted ' +
       ' WHERE SBName LIKE ''' + CHR(i + 64) + '%'' ' +
       ' ORDER BY SBName';
```

Comment: The guys at Advantage do not want to get envolved.